# MVC3 ASP using if statements in model-based elements (TextboxFor / CheckboxFor etc)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I am using a model in MVC3 to populate textboxes on my page like so :

```
<input name="test" value="a" type="radio" id="emp_contributions_gbp" @if (Model.myvalue.ToString() == "x"){<text>checked=true</text>}>
```

This works perfectly fine for saying - "if model.myvalue = x, then check this box"

However, I want to be able to return this model to the controller so I can persist the data should it be updated.

I am now using:
`@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.someField)`  which works perfectly with the model, however I have no idea how I could use `.CheckboxFor` and my IF statements together

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `CheckBoxFor` method like so:

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.SomeProperty, new { checked = Model.myvalue.ToString() == "x" })
```

See [here for the MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830417.aspx) of this overload.

**Update**

Consider using [the `RadioButtonFor` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee830410.aspx) instead:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
  [Required]
  public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
  <div>A: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeProperty, "a")</div>
  <div>B: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeProperty, "b")</div>
  <div>C: @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.SomeProperty, "c")</div>
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

You can then preselect some radio by setting the view model property to the corresponding value:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
  var model = new MyViewModel
  {
    SomeProperty = "a" // select the first radio
  };
  return View(model);
}
```

Comment: the problem i have here is that `someproperty` is an "object" and it expects a "bool". someproperty will either be "a, b or c". Before I had a checkbox for each (A|B|C) with the same name to make a "group"radio selection

Comment: Thanks, I didn't consider using the radio button option. This makes my code a lot tidier.